# Calculate mean and std dev from experiment - no formal params

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, experiment-design, simulation

I am a little lost on how to calculate mean and std dev from an experiment (simulation).

I have run the simulation (10000 times) and it output a set of numbers (10000). Plotting a histogram, it gives me what seems to be a normal distribution. I have used the mean and sd commands and they give me this values.

```
Mean: 9.3982000000
SD:1.2341137549
```

[image: Histogram]

Then I have done an outer loop and rerun a 1000 times the sd and stddev calculus, running 200 times each experiment, so that I could use the mean of means and mean of stds.

```
- 1000 times
   - 200 times
       draw a number based on an algorithm
```

one of the outputs

```
Mean: 9.37336000000
SD:1.2125620067
```

Is this the right way to do it? I cannot find a mean and std value that is always the same. They are close, but not the same. Am I missing some detail or it is expected (this is what confidence interval is about) and the way to do it?

I don't have other formal parameters for calculus. Each number is a return of a program.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve here? What is the ultimate goal of this project?

Comment: Although you do not describe the nature of your "simulation," presumably it included some random values. What is randomness if not the potential to *vary*? Why, then, do you seem surprised that the simulation results vary?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to find the maximum number of different Nets I may have following a specific linkage rule. I wanted to get the exact mean and sd of it, but I am in doubt if the way I am doing is right and if "exact" is not possible.